# I have tried to redirect home page to one new url and inner pages to subdomain

Tags: .htaccess

I have tried to redirect home page to one new url

and

all inner page to another url

I am using

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://example.com [R=301,L]
RewriteRule (.*) http://special.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem?

Comment: All urls are redirecting to http://example.com

Comment: Croise's answer bellow should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ http://example.com [R=301,L]
RewriteRule (.*) http://special.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I am sorry as I am novice to htaccess  

will it work as:  

home page will redirect to example.com  

and all inner pages will redirecting to some another url on respective url  

for example  

[link]: test.com redirect to example.com  

and  

[link]: test.com/hellodolly.html to [link]: special.example.com/hellodolly.html